# Show that the fundamental group of wedge of two circles is non Abelian without actually computing it.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Given that there is a pointed space $(Y,y_0)$, such that it has non Abelian fundamental group, need to show that the fundamental group of the wedge of two circles is non Abelian.

What I was thinking was that if I could define a surjective homomorphism from $\pi_1(S^1 V S^1)$ to $\pi_1(Y)$, then I'd be done.

To that end, I thought it'd be more intuitive to think of loops at the basepoint as continuous maps from $S^1$ rather than as paths from $[0,1]$, but I'm still having trouble coming up with the actual homomorphism, since the space $Y$ is arbitrary.

Comment: I think you are better off just computing it (and actually this computation is pretty important). Do you have Van Kampen's theorem at your disposal?

Comment: I have to say, I find this exercise quite weird: It is about as easy to produce such a space $Y$ as to prove that $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1)$ is free of rank 2 and, hence, nonabelian. To prove the latter one does not need van Kampen's theorem, only that the Cayley graph of $F_2$ is a 4-valent tree $T$, $T/F_2=S^1 \vee S^1$ and that $\pi_1(T)=1$ since each tree is contractible.

Comment: Well, this was an exercise that I was told to do nevertheless. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a surjective homomorphism from $\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1,p)$ to $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$.  You just need a homomorphism whose image contains two noncommuting elements of $\pi_1(Y)$.  With that in mind, let $[a],[b]\in\pi_1(Y,y_0)$ be two noncommuting loops.  How might you use $a$ and $b$ to define a map $S^1\vee S^1\to Y$?

More details are hidden below.

> Just take the map $f:S^1\vee S^1\to Y$ which is given by the loop $a$ on the first copy of $S^1$ and is given by the loop $b$ on the second copy.  Then $f$ gives a homomorphism $f_*:\pi_1(S^1\vee S^1,p)\to\pi_1(Y,y_0)$, where $p$ is the wedge point.  Also, $[a]$ and $[b]$ are in the image of $f_*$, since they are just $f_*([i])$ and $f_*([j])$ where $i$ and $j$ are the loops in $S^1\vee S^1$ that go around each of the circles.

Comment: And, in fact, there are spaces Y with non commutative fundamental groups such that there is no continuous function from the wedge of to circles to Y inducing a surjection on fundamental groups.

Comment: @eric wofsey I realized that shortly after posting the question, and worked it all out, thanks for your answer though!

Comment: I also did realize, it's hopeless to try and get a surjective homomorphism. For example if $Y$ is another circle attached to the wedge of two circles!